# If I make an object using a list and the same constructor, does that mean after I make it I can no longer reference it?

Tags: java, loops, object, arraylist, foreach

I've created the following code to make Region objects that have information in them. (Coordinates, election data, etc). I'm wondering if I can no longer reference these after they are put into the memory (i.e. they are overwritten each time it goes through the object(Loop)) Thanks!

```
for (File object: fileList){
        try {
        region = new Region(object.getName());
            System.out.println(region);
        region.getSelection();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

If I can, how would I reference that object?
Excuse me if this question or a similar question has been answered. I couldn't find one similar enough to know what exactly this code does.

Comment: In your loop, yeah, you wouldn't be able to access them again. Put them in some sort of data structure, i.e. a List<Region>, Set<Region>, or some other Collection<Region>.

Comment: @Meguy26 Thanks, I made a List of regions and added each.

Comment: As Meguy 26 said, put then in a list or an array. Declare the data structure outside of the for loop and add the region for every time the loop runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
List<Region> regionList = new ArrayList<>();
List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>(); 

   for (File object: fileList){
                try {
                regionList.add(new Region(object.getName()));
                region.getSelection();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
```